# mysql CONCAT(): Unknown column ''-'' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, concatenation

I am trying to get this: `2014-3` from the following query:

```
$this->db->select("CONCAT(YEAR(start_date),'-',MONTH(start_date)) yearmonth")
->from("events")
->where("event_id", 5)->get();
```

Am i using the concatenation function in a wrong way? please help!

Comment: Why not use [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jus t change it to this ...

```
$this->db->select("CONCAT(YEAR(start_date),'-',MONTH(start_date)) yearmonth",false)
->from("events")
->where("event_id", 5)->get();
```

U need to add another argument FALSE in the select function to execute this query

Answer (score 1):

The only explanation for this error

> Unknown column ''-'' in 'field list'

would be if you used backticks instead of (single)quotes. Anyway, another way to write this would be

```
$this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%Y-%m') yearmonth")
->from("events")
->where("event_id", 5)->get();
```

Comment: it works when i run `DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%Y-%m') yearmonth` in PHPMYADMIN but does not work in the query in the application!